# Laravel 7, Keep Query Parameters in the URL

Tags: laravel, url, query-string

I'm working with query params. I'm fetching records against my query param, but when I pass data to view, it removes query parameter from the url. When I use die function to print values it keeps query params in URL but when I load view it removes my query params. You can see in the image that Query Params are removed from the URl after fetching the results according to the Query Params. [image]

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{
   $scholarships= Scholarship::where('name','like','%'.$request->search.'%')->where(['status'=>1])->orderBy('sort_order')->paginate(2)->withQueryString();

   return view('search-page', ["scholarships"=>$scholarships]);
}
```

Comment: what happens when you directly paste the url with query in the browser?

Comment: What does an URL look like when you have searched something?

Comment: Even when I paste the query params in the url, It show the same. Query params gets removed.